# Why is jQuery to Controller Action clearing Session object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, session

I have

```
$("#cn-btn-cust-slt").button().click(function () {
        $("#cn-dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            position: { my: "left", at: "top+350", of: window },
            width: 700,
            height: 600,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Customer Selection',
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                $("#cn-dialog").load("/Customer/CustomerSearch");
            },
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

which returns a partial view and opens it in the dialog

Problem is the session values are lost when .load() calls the action (debugged to ascertain).

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5 in VS 2013 and running locally from VS. Cookies are enabled.

I've tried everything I can find on the internet without success. Session is working fine throughout the application except with jquery dialog.

Has anyone any idea? - pulling my hair out (what's left of it)

**EDIT**
Here is the controller action that is called by the jquery above

```
public ActionResult CustomerSearch()
{
    string test = SessionManager.DisplayDateFormat; //zit

    return View();
}
```

It simply returns a view but the session variable has been lost before it returns. For debugging purposes I added the test variable above which gets set to null. I use the code below to get and set session variables which is working fine in all other parts of the application.

```
public class SessionManager
    {
        //Session variable constants
        public const string DATEFORMATVAR = "DisplayDateFormat";

        //use generics to work with any type
        public static T Read<T>(string variable)
        {
            object value = HttpContext.Current.Session[variable];
            if (value == null)
                return default(T);
            else
                return ((T)value);
        }

        public static void Write(string variable, object value)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[variable] = value;
        }

        public static string DisplayDateFormat
        {
            get
            {
                return Read<string>(DATEFORMATVAR);
            }
            set
            {
                Write(DATEFORMATVAR, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've successfully debugged the session variable in the controller that serves the view containing the jquery .load() call above.

The Session variable value is being lost between the .load() call and the target action method. I am hoping to hold a limited amount of data in session - in this case the display date format = DD/MM/YY.

Comment: can you say, what do you mean by session values? Values on loaded form? values that you send to openning form? Not clear.

Comment: Post your server side code also. Which helps lot for more understanding what you want exact?

Comment: teo van kot - thanks for reading - I mean a value or variable of the session object is lost but in reality I think the session object is lost.

Comment: Prog - thanks for the reply - as requested I've added all relevant code.

Comment: @radiator MVC don't have session like WebForms.
If you want to store your variable and post it then in particial View you should use `@Html.Hidden(SessionVal)` on you particial view

Comment: teo van kot - i'm not trying to post a session variable - i'm trying to access the session object from the server - problem is it appears to have been reset when hitting the server because the session id is the same before and after (directly before the .load() call and in the controller action) but the session variable has gone because reference to it returns null.

Comment: @teo van kot - MVC uses exactly the same session state as WebForms. It's all ASP.NET, take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @radiator - your `test` variable returns as empty string? Where do you set `SessionManager.DisplayDateFormat`? Can you post that code? We're using Ajax calls on our current MVC project and session state works as expected, so I'm not sure where you see the problem.